# Metro UI Tile/Speed Dial Web Project ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-metro

not sure where to start with this one so here goes...

I'm wanting to make some sort of a Speed Dial type website/web page with similar functionality to the Opera Speed Dial where you can add Hyperlinks to a page and they appear as big buttons and carry you off to the destination page/site of the hyperlink, ultimately I want users to be able to add their own as well as select from a list of pre-approved links and I would like this to be saved to our SQL database... That's not so much the problem though as I have some sort of idea how to add the DIV's / Hyperlinks from code behind...

The problem is, I would really love to have this page following the Metro Style UI, tiles all tight within a grid sort of layout ideally with Drag and Droppable functionality, possibly resizable tiles as well and I would like to be able to add an image to the whole surface of a tile where necessary (like Windows 8 Metro tiles) I've ran around the net this morning looking for ways of doing this and have found a few examples i.e. JQuery Masonry (Doesn't seem to support Draggable tiles) and Packery but I'm just posting here to see if anyone has any little bit of possible advice toward this project and where to start maybe?

I have Visual Studio 2010 and I wish to use ASP.Net with either VB or C# as code behind and I have access to the Telerik components if anyone has advice from that end although I've been through the Demos this morning and couldn't find anything regarding the general layout framework of this (unless I've missed something?)

Anyway, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Sorry for the half-self-plug here, but do you mean something akin to: http://steffanjam.es/ ?

Comment: Ye, that looks pretty good, doesn't seem to be draggable/droppable however and it only has one Tile Size? But it's definately along the right lines... I believe it's PHP also? But yes, that sort of thing.

Comment: It sounds like the majority of this project will be done clientside - Javascript is definitely the way to go. You'll then want to look into having Javascript send back layout changes to your code-behind. Telerik's Controls are unlikely to be of much help here.

Comment: Ahh, ok :) That's a good bit of advice for me to start having a play with :) Thanks!

Comment: To be a little more specific, for the drag and drop you will find plenty of jQuery libraries that will handle that for you. Moving the layout around as you drag though? That's all on you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have understood your requirement then best thing will be you can refer [Drop Tiles](http://www.droptiles.com) and download the sample code too in .net